# Debian to VDI or IMG

Tags: virtualbox, debian, conversion, xen, vdi

I have a debian server that I can't really shut down because the company stops.
How can I convert it from physical disk to VirtualBox or Xen without shutting it down?
I don't want to play with the live system.

Comment: Does the server currently use LVM? Does the company have any procedures for scheduled upgrades/downtime?